# How should I divide a large (~50Gb) dataset into training, test, and validation sets?

Tags: python, numpy, dataset

I have a large dataset. It's currently in the form of uncompressed numpy array files that were created with `numpy.array.tofile()`. Each file is approximately 100000 rows of 363 floats each. There are 192 files totalling 52 Gb.

I'd like to separate a random fifth of this data into a test set, and a random fifth of that test set into a validation set.

In addition, I can only train on 1 Gb at a time (limitation of GPU's onboard memory) So  I need to randomize the order of all the data so that I don't introduce a bias by training on the data in the order it was collected.

My main memory is 8 Gb in size. Can any recommend a method of randomizing and partitioning this huge dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer I needed at [External shuffle: shuffling large amount of data out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628072/external-shuffle-shuffling-large-amount-of-data-out-of-memory)

Basically, you find a hash that is sufficiently random for numbers, (in this case I'm using [Murmur3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smhasher)) and then you apply external merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a unique sequential number to each row, then choose a random sample of those numbers, then serially extract each relevant row to a new file.

Comment: I can't do that because the seek operations would be too slow.