# How to select 10 thousand random lines from a 44 million lines file

Tags: linux, bash, perl, sorting, awk

I tried to use `shuf` to shuffle the file but it's taking too long; the process was killed by the hosting admin.  I have the cheapest Linux Bluehost plan.

```
shuf MMM.csv
```

file has 44M lines, file size is 7439641823 bytes, using `sort -R` even worse, thinking about splitting the file into 44 files, but it's going to be not very random, any ideas would be much appreciated

What I want is to shuffle the file, then extract the first 10000 lines

The file was sorted, for business reason, the 10000 lines cannot be sorted

Comment: Hmm. I can think of some various algorithms for this -- one is to generate a 44-million-long list of random numbers or UUIDs, and use that list as the sort key; could sort individual splitfiles with that key (indexing into the full list for appropriate offsets) and then do a merge-sort pass after. However, before getting into the details -- what's the actual use case? How random does it actually need to be?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? This looks like an XY problem to me.

Comment: You could download the file from the hoster and do it locally. Probably the biggest problem will be the RAM usage. 7GB is quite a large file.

Comment: if I load the file into sqlite3, will that help?

Comment: As Sobrique says, this can be optimised best by knowing your end purpose. A *shuffle* is never an end in itself, and is usually used to pick a random subset from a sample. What are you using your shuffle for?

Comment: You need an "external" shuffle. Some ideas already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628072/external-shuffle-shuffling-large-amount-of-data-out-of-memory

Comment: @JeffY: That link would solve different question, but the OP is asking for a way to shuffle a 44M record file faster that `shuf`

Comment: Excuse me, but I think that `shuf` died because it ran out of memory at the Bluehost virtual machine, not killed because it took too long. You all are focused on looking for a real fast solution while ignoring the issue of the system resources it's going to take while shuffling the file. I also think that you should first find something that does the job (`shuf` didn't) before going all the way into optimizing it. (Besides, my _rejected_ python program only took slightly twice the time it takes to copy the file).

Comment: Your edit completely changes the problem. All you need to do is select 10,000 lines at random from the file; you don't need to shuffle the entire 44 million lines. This is what @Sobrique meant about "XY problem."

Comment: Yes I want 10000 random lines from a 44M-line file

Comment: Then post a question saying that, not that you have to shuffle a 44M line file! Additionally post an example with a file that's, say, 10 lines long and asking how to print, say, 4 lines from that and show the expected output.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 10,000 results?

Comment: I agree with @Locoluis, testing ``shuf`` shows that it's peak RSS is something like size of file * 2.  On a small rented vm this is likely to be too much

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use "shuf" with the -n (“output at most COUNT lines”) option.

Compare:

```
$ time (seq 1 44000000 | shuf > /tmp/shuffled)
user  0m58.234s
sys   0m4.394s

$ time (seq 1 44000000 | shuf -n 10000 > /tmp/shuffled)
user   0m25.493s
sys    0m1.771s
```

(These timings were taken on a sadly old 2.53GHz Mac.)

NOTE: in some environments, "shuf" might be available as "gshuf".

Answer (score 2):

Given your new requirement to print some fixed number of random lines from a file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    srand()
    for (i=1;i<=outNum;i++) {
        if (tgts[int(rand()*inNum)+1]++) {
            i--
        }
    }
}
NR in tgts

$ seq 44000000 > file44m

$ time awk -v inNum=$(wc -l < file44m) -v outNum=10000 -f tst.awk file44m > file10k
real    0m17.676s
user    0m17.238s
sys     0m0.404s

$ sort -u file10k | wc -l
10000
```

The above only stores `outNum` line numbers in memory so there should be no memory issues. See below for how it works on a small file:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ awk -v inNum=$(wc -l < file) -v outNum=4 -f tst.awk file
6
8
9
10

$ awk -v inNum=$(wc -l < file) -v outNum=4 -f tst.awk file
1
6
7
9

$ awk -v inNum=$(wc -l < file) -v outNum=3 -f tst.awk file
3
7
8

$ awk -v inNum=$(wc -l < file) -v outNum=3 -f tst.awk file
4
5
6
```

Comment: Did you read the whole 7GB file twice so that you could get the number of records on the first pass? That's very diligent :-)

Comment: Turned out using `wc -l` to count the number of lines in advance made the script significantly faster (17 secs instead of 31 secs execution time) so I updated my answer. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to use:

```
perl -ne 'print if (rand() < .001)' MMM.csv > MMM.out
```

and get a subset of 10000 from it

But I still want solution to shuffle a 44M-line file under 10 seconds, is this even possible on a shared hosting account ?

Comment: "I want a Ferrari, but all I have is a 1983 Datsun. How can I drive my Datsun differently to achieve the same level of performance as a Ferrari?" Throwing more hardware at a problem isn't always the right solution, but this time it is.

Comment: not even a Datsun, it's an old 1990s bike, sweetheart !

Comment: $ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       32946460 kB
MemFree:          818016 kB
Buffers:         2797180 kB
Cached:         19553908 kB
SwapCached:       427952 kB
Active:         15633248 kB
Inactive:       11417452 kB
Active(anon):    5170372 kB
Inactive(anon):  3517568 kB
Active(file):   10462876 kB
Inactive(file):  7899884 kB
Unevictable:       25856 kB
Mlocked:           25880 kB
SwapTotal:       8388604 kB
SwapFree:        5296460 kB
Dirty:              3272 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4305652 kB
Mapped:           384584 kB
Shmem:           3984020 kB

Comment: It's a shared server, so I only get a slice, probably a kernel demon will kick me out when certain threshold is reached

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up a year or so ago. please let me know how it goes in your tests. If your input is sorted but you do not want the results sorted then shuf the output.

It looks to me like your input to output size is large enough you will want to get the progressive skip part uncommented and working. I did not need it and so it is untested as far as I recall.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -F

# reservoir_sample.awk

# the basic reservoir algorithm is due to Alan Waterman (according to Knuth) 
# Vitter (85) improved timing and made sampling uniform
# http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/vitter.pdf
# 
# Expect a K parameter which is the size of the intended sample
# 
# reservoir_sample.awk -v K=1000   population.list


BEGIN {
    # give srand a fixed seed for reproducubility
    # or a variable for diversity    
    srand(systime() + PROCINFO["pid"]); 

    # 23 is a magic number between 10 & 40 as per Vitter  
    threshold = 23 * K; 
}

# fill the reservoir
NR <= K {   reservoir[NR] = $0 }

# replace item in resovior with current item 
# on probability of K / (NR) 
NR > K {
    uniform_probability = int(rand() * NR + 0.5);
    if (uniform_probability  <= K) 
        reservoir[uniform_probability] = $0

    # when the population is large with respect to sample size K
    # test fewer items from the population for inclusion in the reservoir   
    #if(NR < threshold){
    #   skip = 
    #   for (i=0 ; i < skip; i++) getline()  
    #}
}

# and Bobs yer uncle
END {   for(item in reservoir) {print reservoir[item]} }

# without the progressivly larger steps through the population
# this would not approach uniform since for larger the populations 
# more earlier candidates are replaced more than later candidates.
```