Is there an algorithm for thoroughly shuffling big datasets in-place with limited memory?
I have a large HDF5 file containing a single table. The table itself contains collections of ordered data that themselves are quite large but are stored contiguously in blocks. I need to shuffle the data efficiently such that the individual points are shuffled.
As an example, let's say I have a 400 GB HDF5 file stored on a 512 GB SSD. I also have 16 GB of RAM available. The file itself contains 40 blocks of data with 1000 ordered samples each, for example:



block
sample index
data




0
0
65465265


0
1
53124588


0
2
35802482


0
3
43325488


...
...
...


0
999
35311531


1
0
43564784


1
1
45315000


1
2
45684834


1
3
34583688


...
...
...


39
999
00650846



I want to shuffle the data completely, so that both the blocks and sample indices are mixed (so I can't, for example, load contiguous blocks into memory and shuffle then rewrite them.
The best approach that I have for this relies on pandas' read_hdf() function. I maintain a mapping of the indices in the original file that are shuffled, accessed with a call like the following:
batch = pd.read_hdf(self.input_path, key=self.key, where=pd.Index(batch_indices))
shuffled in memory, and then rewritten. Unfortunately, accessing random indices with the where argument is incredibly slow–there must be a better way.

Random disk access is always slow. Random index access in HDF5 is particularly slow because the library has a poorly optimized implementation for this. And if the HDF5 dataset is stored with chunks (or worse, compression), it can only allow random chunk access in decent performance. I suggest a random on-disk shuffle roughly as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50420446/17167312 But you need 400 GB temporary disk storage, 800 if you don't want to overwrite the original data. Is the approach understandable?

Basically this: Think merge-sort but as a random shuffle. Start by loading, let's say 4 GB blocks of data. Shuffle it and store it back to disk. That gives you 100 blocks. Pick pairs of blocks, both length N. Shuffle them. To do this, generate a random integer sequence of 50% 1 and 0 length 2*N. Read sequentially from both blocks. Depending on the next integer in the sequence, pick the next output row from block 0 or 1. Write them back to disk. Repeat recursively. You can try the same with shuffling 4, 8, 16 blocks at a time

@Homer512 That sounds biased. For example if you merge [1,2] with [3,4], won't you produce the permutation [1,2,3,4] with 25% probability but the permutation [1,3,2,4] with only 12.5% probability?

@nocomment Well, let's try it out: https://pastebin.com/GNGebALF Looks fine to me. The linked answer also contains some proof.

@Homer512 Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you meant this.

Please clarify the H5 schema. Is a block a dataset, and the sample index the row index? If so, what is data? (clearly it's not a singe integer value b/c that's not enough data for a 40GB file).
