# merge sort recursion not clear how the sorting of array is achieved please help to understand the code

Tags: c++, mergesort

can someone help me to understand how the sorting is being done using recursion code of merge sort

```
void merge_sort(int arr[],int low,int up)
{
    int mid;
    int temp[MAX];
    if(low<up)//if more than one element
    {
        mid=(low+up)/2;
        merge_sort(arr,low,mid);//sort lower array
        merge_sort(arr,mid+1,up);//sort upper array
        merge(arr,temp,low,mid,mid+1,up);//merge the two arrays to temp array
        copy(arr,temp,low,up);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this gif](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Merge-sort-example-300px.gif) from the wiki page for Merge Sort. Is there any specific line you are confused about? Or the overall algorithm?

Comment: @CoryKramer i am unable to imagine how the array got sorted using recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is a duplicate question
from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502533/explanation-of-merge-sort-for-dummies) where the explanation is very clear. Is not in C++ but I think it is enough to understand excluding the language.